# Understanding mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql select query with following condition:

```
Select...
FROM ...
...
AND c.deleted != '1'
```

In the table, there will always be more records with deleted = '0' than deleted = '1'

so I want to know which is faster:

```
AND c.deleted != '1'
```

or

```
AND c.deleted = '0'
```

or are they same?

Comment: This appears to be better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com. You could also run both queries and look at the execution time to see which is faster. My guess is it will be negligible.

Comment: Regardless of speed the equals condition is, in my opinion, clearer to read and understand for the next person who comes along and has to look at and work with your code. In SQL it's a single equal sign not 2 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

they are roughly the same.

mysql will have to analyse each row to determine the value of `c.deleted` unless the field is indexed.  if the field is indexed the equality test will be faster, but probably not by much.  you can always run some tests to determine for yourself.